# @ManyToOne Lazy loading not working

Tags: jpa

I've seen other posts about this problem, but have found no answer to my own troubles. I have

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name= ServerSpringConstants.COMPANY)
    public class Company implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9104996853272739161L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "companyID")
    private long companyID;

    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Division.class, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable (name = "companyDivisionJoinTable",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="companyID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="divisionID")
    )
    private Set<Division> divisions = new HashSet<>();

    public long getCompanyID() {
        return companyID;
    }

    public Set<Division> getDivisions() {
        return divisions;
    }

    public void setDivisions(Set<Division> divisions) {
        this.divisions = divisions;
    }
}
```

On the other side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= ServerSpringConstants.DIVISION)
public class Division implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3685914604737207530L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "divisionID")
    private long divisionID;

    @ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, targetEntity = Company.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE
            }
            )
    @JoinColumn(name="companyID", referencedColumnName = "companyID")
    private Company company;

    public long getDivisionID() {
        return divisionID;
    }

    public void setDivisionID(long divisionID) {
        this.divisionID = divisionID;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

}
```

Yet for some reason, LAZY loading not working. I'm using JPA. I'm calling back the companies, and their enclosing divisions from within a 'User' class -- the pertinent part

```
 @ManyToMany (targetEntity = Company.class,
        cascade={
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.REFRESH},
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinTable (
        name="companyUserJoinTable",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="companyID")
)
private Set<Company> company = new HashSet<>();
```

I've searched out existing threads, and have tried adding various suggestions, but nothing has helped!
Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A Company has an eager fetching on Division and you are accessing Divisions via companies if I got it well. Which lazy loading then? If you go the other way and try to load a division first then it wont have the referenced company loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Grid. This is giving me a headache! I'm pulling back users, which for each individual user, pulls back a list of their companies, and their divisions. Currently, because LAZY is failing, I'm getting Users, with Companies, that contain Divisions, that contain Companies, that contain Divisions etc. etc. Hence why I need lazy loading. I wanted a bi-directional relationship, because I will need to sometimes pull data from Divisions to Companies when running reports.

Comment: Add a @MappedBy at one side of the bidirectional association (you decide which one). And get rid of those targetEntity attributes.

Comment: Cheers again for your answer. But in order for Companies to pull back Divisions, I will need the Company side to own, and there is no mappedBy for ManyToOne.

Comment: It works if I take out the join on the Division side. But then I can't pull back companies from Divisions. But anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading the divisions set eagerly (with fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and you have a bidirectional association, divisions will be initialized with the parent reference to company. I can't see any problem with it. Jpa loaded the full object tree because you just told it so. A company contains divisions which contain a back reference to the company that loaded them. 
To understand it better, since the reason for lazy loading is to reduce the data loaded from database, the owning company is already loaded in session for the divisions, so why not setting the association too?

The @ManyToOne association on the other side takes effect if you load divisions first.

To be more correct with your mapping add also a @MappedBy attribute to the one part of the association. This does not affect fetching behavior but will prevent double updates to the database issued by both ends of the association.

Comment: Thanks again. As I saw it: USERS would pull Eagerly on COMPANIES, COMPANIES would pull Eagerly on DIVISIONS. DIVISIONS, however, would pull lazily on COMPANIES. But what you are saying, is that USERS will cause the whole chain to pull Eagerly? ---- Indeed the LAZY pull does work if I pull back from the DIVISION DAO. So it's the parent that sets the pull type, right the way down the chain?